# height control - multiple step form without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, forms

The following is the script I am using:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-152085.html

How can you have a container around a multiple step webform without the height/absolute positioning screwing stuff up?

Some of the steps I have have are different heights, and also with absolute positioning you can't have a wrapper with a background color.

My problem is the height is crazy because div's are being hidden but the height is still taken

Any alternative with the same script that allows a wrapper bg color and a height that alternates, instead of flooding the scrollbar?

EDIT: Here is a live example (notice the scrollbar issue?)

http://fastfolio.com/div-test/test.html

if the steps are different heights, the scrolling hurts. maybe some kind of #top fix or something? how do you get it to read the height and adjust accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Check jQuery as this will make handling the scroll easier.

In your example HTML page, replace the onclick with a function that checks current height of the div ( $(this).parent().parent().height() ) and the scroll position of the body ( $(body).scrollTop() ).

If the height is smaller than scrolTop then use the scrollTop to move the body up.

jQuery will take you 30 minutes to get your head around, but it's well worth it and wil solve a lot of queries like this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you have a sample of what you mean? I am showing an example of a light version of the form I am working on, the bare bones - I am already using onClick for form verification. I would need to write multiple instances or be able to execute more than one function. Any ideas?

I am a visual learner, so seeing it helps...

Comment: just to clarify, how would the function be written? thanks! (and if possible, how to add multiple functions including the to top)

Comment: something like this, but instead of only working on window resize, it should work when the div height resizes, or maybe it resets and forces user to #top ?

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/

Comment: i found how to create a function to scroll to top so at least with different heights you're not stuck at the bottom with no content, but the height of the invisible div still stays for some reason

function jumpScroll() {
    window.scroll(0,0); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets
}

Comment: i realize part of the issue may be with css visibility: hidden as it still maintains the height of the previous div

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using visibility to toggle the element shown but rather the CSS style of "display" (between "block" and "none" will do what you're after).

The pagination should also not rely on IDs - far better for you to use an array, and a "current state" holder. The "next" submit entity for should

http://consulting.euphemize.net/jack.shepherd/pagination-form/

Better options held in here :)